# android studio application not able to run a separate class

Tags: android-studio

I am writing an android studio application I the code bellow is the class I created if I run the code from the MainActivity class it works perfectly but separated into its own class it crashes the app I assume this is due to my not understanding how to use classes in android studio can some one explain what I am doing wrong

this is the class in question

```
package edu.bsu.cs222.teamc_cardinal_calorie_counter;

import android.app.Application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Created by Benaiah on 3/6/2018.
 */

public class FileData extends Application {
    public String openFile(){
        String text = "sumthing went wrong";
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = getAssets().open("boarshead.txt");
            int size = inputStream.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            inputStream.read(buffer);
            inputStream.close();
            text = new String(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

this is the MainActivity class that calls it

```
package edu.bsu.cs222.teamc_cardinal_calorie_counter;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.read);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FileData fileData = new FileData();
                textView.setText(fileData.openFile());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import FileData in your MainActivity and make openFile method as a static method.

Comment: how do I use the getAssets() if its static

Comment: Non-static methods like getAssets() can't be used in a static method. And non-static methods can't be accessed from outside the class.

Comment: so how do I accuses the file from the static method will I have to pass it as a parameter?

Comment: You can send a local broadcast for this. And pass parameters as extras with the intend

Comment: thank you for your help passing it as a parameter worked thank you so much